# How do I keep two Datomic Cloud clients in sync?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I have two [Datomic clients](https://docs.datomic.com/client-api/datomic.client.api.html) open in two REPLs connected to the same database in Datomic Cloud. After transacting data in REPL 1, the connection in REPL 2 is not aware that time has advanced until a query is executed.

**REPL 1**

I transact some data bringing the `{:db-after {:t 768}}`

```
(d/transact conn {:tx-data [{:person/first-name "Alice"}]})
=>
{:db-before {:database-id "<some-squuid>",
             :db-name "datomic-test",
             :t 767,
             :next-t 768,
             :history false,
             :type :datomic.client/db},
 :db-after {:database-id "<some-squuid>",
            :db-name "datomic-test",
            :t 768,
            :next-t 769,
            :history false,
            :type :datomic.client/db},
 :tx-data [#datom[13194139534080 50 #inst"2018-05-15T09:18:22.565-00:00" 13194139534080 true]
           #datom[43976067064531301 73 "Alice" 13194139534080 true]],
 :tempids {}}
```

---

```
(d/db conn)
=>
{:t 768,
 :next-t 769,
 :db-name "datomic-test",
 :database-id "<some-squuid>",
 :type :datomic.client/db}
```

**REPL 2**

I get the latest known database value, but it's still at `{:t 767}`

```
(d/db conn)
=>
{:t 767,
 :next-t 768,
 :db-name "datomic-test",
 :database-id "<some-squuid>",
 :type :datomic.client/db}
```

Repeatedly calling [d/db](https://docs.datomic.com/client-api/datomic.client.api.html#var-db) will forever return the database at `:t` 767, one transaction behind REPL 1. It's locked there no matter how long I wait.

... Until I run a query:

```
(d/q '[:find (pull ?person [*])
       :in $ ?person-name
       :where
       [?person :person/first-name ?person-name]] 
     (d/db conn)
     "Alice")
=> []
```

Querying for the recently transacted "Alice" returns an empty collection because the database value returned from `d/db` in REPL 2 is old. However, the action of querying advances the database returned from `d/db`. Now it's "caught up":

```
(d/db conn)
=>
{:t 768,
 :next-t 769,
 :db-name "datomic-test",
 :database-id "<some-squuid>",
 :type :datomic.client/db}
```

And re-running the same query returns the data transacted from REPL 1:

```
(d/q '[:find (pull ?person [*])
       :in $ ?person-name
       :where
       [?person :person/first-name ?person-name]] 
     (d/db conn)
     "Alice")
=> [[{:db/id 43976067064531301, :person/first-name "Alice"}]]
```

Datomic's peer API has a [sync](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/clojure/index.html#datomic.api/sync) function which seems to solve this problem for on-prem, however the Datomic Client API doesn't appear to have anything similar.

Given that REPL 1 and REPL 2 represent two independent systems, how can I tell them to always use the latest version of the database without executing a bogus query?